# Advice on cross browser testing techniques and best practices

Tags: browserstack

I am hopefully looking for a little insight into what other Front End Developers use for cross browser testing. My strategy has been to check a handful of actual real devices; Windows PC, Mac, Samsung s6 , Iphone 5s, Ipad and the Device Emulator in Chrome Dev Tools.

I know there are other tools like Browserstack - which I have used only briefly once a couple of years ago.

I am shortly starting a new role and they use macs for everything. So, in the absence of a windows machine, testing IE will need some sort of emulator like Browserstack?

Has anyone got any advice on techniques or tools they use for cross browser testing? Is browserstack the way to go or do you prefer real devices? **If you are on a mac how do you test IE?**

Would appreciate any advice - thanks :-)

Comment: Just wanted to clarify, BrowserStack offers real desktop and mobile browsers for testing.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mukesh. Is that what you use for testing IE on a mac?